# Should positive and negative unit tests for one method have individual tests?

Tags: unit-testing

Say, for example, I have a method that checks for valid UK postcodes. I have written a unit test for that method that tests when a correct UK postcode is passed in, the method returns true.

Should I create a separate unit test to test for an incorrect UK postcode, or do it in the same unit test?

Thanks

Comment: Look up test cases, test suites etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit

Comment: What language is this going to be for? There are a lot of frameworks out there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create seperate test cases for each case. This will give you confidence that any future code that calls this method will work, also if you refactor you can see exactly which test fails, instead of just seeing 1test fail and have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd write a few tests that check it works correctly with different types of valid postcodes (NE1 2XX, NE21 2XX, E1 3YY, etc. trying out different valid combinations of characters and numbers) and several failing tests with invalid ones of different types (e.g. NEI 3XX).

Answer (score 1):

What I use to do is to create two functions, say `test_valid_data()` and `test_invalid_data()`, and two data sets, say `valid_data[]` and `invalid_data[]`. I then write four test procedures:

- test_valid_data(valid_data[]) : *This test should pass*
- test_valid_data(invalid_data[]) : *This test should fail*
- test_invalid_data(valid_data[]) : *This test should fail*
- test_invalid_data(invalid_data[]) : *This test should pass*

Working like this allows you to pinpoint failing test according to a particular data set. That behavior would be hard to achieve with only one big test. It also validate that valid data are not considered invalid and vice versa.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I think this is a really interesting method.

Comment: Following your example with UK postcodes, create two testing functions: `test_valid_postcode()` and `test_invalid_postcode()` 
After, create two data sets: `valid_postcode[]` and `invalid_postcode[]`. The former should contain a list of valid UK postcode to test against (ex: M1 1AA, B33 8TH, EC1A 1BB, etc). The later should contain a list of invalid UK postcode (ex: M1 1AAAAAAAA, B33 8TH BCB 123, etc).
You should now test each data set against each functions. That gives you four possible combination. Two of them should pass the test and the two other should fail.

Comment: Since you are aware that two of the tests should fail, you can handle it properly. If one of the two test that should fail passes, you know that there is something wrong with your code.